# Nested timeouts in AngularJs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it correct to have a structure like this in a Angular 1.x controller, with a $timeout included in another $timeout?

```
$timeout(function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        callbackFn($event);
    });
});
```

To be more specific:

I have a timeout in a directive link function and another timeout in the directive's controller. Right now they are executed in a random order each time the directive is rendered. I found the solution with the two nested timeouts to be working, but I'm not sure it it's okay to use them in this way.

An example: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/jYOGPO

Comment: Define "correct"

Comment: but why? the syntax seems fine, but usually you would add the total time and use only one `$timeout`, so why have both?

Comment: @AlonEitan I mean, to be sure that it can't have some bad side effects in some yet unseen cases.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I need to move that funcion call to the very end of the callstack, which already have some function calls at the end moved there by a previous $timeout. That's why I've added the two non-delay timeouts.

Comment: What Aleksey wrote explains why I asked you to define "correct" - It should work, but I can't understand why do you need it in the first place (I don't say you're necessarily wrong with this, I just don't understand it)

Comment: @neptune relying on callback delay seems like a bad practice, surely there must be an alternative solution, perhaps your questions should be different

Comment: @neptune Perhaps it's a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Can you please try to explain in more details what you were tring to achive in the first place, it could lead to a new approachs for you

Comment: @AlonEitan I've added an short explanation of my exact issue.

Comment: @neptune Why not using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) (Promise) for this? If you need to control the order of something that is asynchronous, you can resolve a promise and inside the resolve function you can trigger the next one

Comment: @AlonEitan I have something like this: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/jYOGPO Idk if $q can be implemented in this case. I just want t2 to be executed after t1.

Comment: maybe it's the case of using directive [priorities](http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects) in the right order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle **requested** two or more functions with order (in your case between directive and controller *[first directive and then controller]*), you can pass Model between them.

**More explaination**

> having a **Model** in application is one of powerful *strategy* to make your app flexible.

**for example**

```
$scope.model = { anything: false }
```

if we try to pass this `$scope` in our directive , then we have two way binding between controller and our directives, i show you how it work in your sample.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('cDir', function($timeout){
return {
  restrinct: 'E',
  controller: 'appCtrl',
  template: 'cdir template',
  scope: {
    ready: '='
  },
  link: function(scope){
    console.log('t1');
    scope.ready = true;
  }
}})

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.ready = false;
    $scope.$watch('ready', function(isReady){
      if(isReady){
         console.log('t2');
      }
    })
}]);
```

**view**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <c-dir ready="ready"></c-dir>
</div>
```

There we define `$scope.ready` as model to directive, `console.log('t2')` show up when `ready` is `true` from the directive; we use `$watch` as listener for our `$scope`.